# Play framework: How to set error message for specific field in dynamic form

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to show an error message for an individual field just below it. But can't find in documentation how to set it.

My controllers actions:

Action 1: Creates initial view by wrapping model in Form

```
    public static Result retrieveEcommerceTransaction(Long id) {
    Logger.debug("InstantCheck:retrieveEcommerceTransaction()-Retrieving transaction for txn id : " + id);

    if(id != null && (id instanceof Long)) {
        EcommerceRequestManager ecomRequestManager = new EcommerceRequestManager();
        CustomerTransactionProfile customerTransactionProfile = ecomRequestManager.populateCustomerTxnProfile(id);
        Cache.set(String.valueOf(id), customerTransactionProfile);
        if(customerTransactionProfile != null) {
            instantCheckForm = instantCheckForm.fill(customerTransactionProfile);
            return ok(views.html.instantcheck.index.render(instantCheckForm));
        }           
    } 

    return  badRequest(Constants.STATUS_CODE_MISSING_PARAMETERS);
}
```

Action 2: Gets called when form in view is submitted. Using dynamic form to get form values.

```
    public static Result checkLoanEligibility() {
    String actionUrl = null;
    DynamicForm form = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    String pan = form.get("n_pan");
        if(pan.isEmpty() || pan.length() != 10) {
        form.reject(new ValidationError("pan", "Invalid PAN value. Please enter a valid PAN value"));
    } else {
                    actionUrl =  <code for calling manager class for post processing.....>
    }

    return ok(actionUrl);
}
```

View:

```
<div>

<div>
<label for="">PAN</label>
<div>
    <input id="i_pan" type="text" name="n_pan" value="@instantCheckForm.field("PAN").value()"/>
    @for(error <- form("pan").errors) {
        <p>@error.message</p>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

Error message:

```
not found: value form
```

at line

```
@for(error <- form("pan").errors) {
```

I have followed Play documentation to create this piece of code. Whats wrong when using form("pan").errors?

Is there any template that can show how to use dynamic form and Form wrapping models to create and process html forms?

Regards,
Suraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not passing a Form[CustomerTransactionProfile] to the template in the second action. That's why the variable form is not declared in the template. You need it to pass the rejection around.